# Correct way of nesting dynamic resource controllers with Laravel when creating a REST API

Tags: rest, laravel, routes, controllers

I've found good information on handling nested resource controllers and passing multiple constraints but seem to find nothing on this specific problem (probably cause I'm thinking about it all wrong!).

If I want to create the following in my API

- /cars (show all cars)
- /cars/1 (show carId = 1)
- /cars/1/performance (show performance for carId=1)
- /cars/1/performance/parts (show performance of parts for carId=1)
- /cars/1/performance/parts/1 (show performance of partId=1 for carId=1)
- /cars/performance (show performance of all cars)
- /cars/performance/parts
- /parts
- /parts/1 etc... (same for parts as cars above)

would I have to create routes and controllers for most of them in this fashion

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'myAwesomeCarApi'), function()
{
    Route::resource('cars', 'CarsController'); 
    Route::resource('cars/performance', 'CarsPerController');
    Route::resource('cars/performance/parts', 'CarsPerPartsController');
    Route::resource('cars.performance/parts', 'CarsPerPartsController');
    Route::resource('parts', 'PartsController');
    Route::resource('parts/performance', 'PartsPerController');
    etc...
});
```

or is there some trickery I'm missing for creating dynamic controllers e.g only 3 (CarController, PartsController, PerformanceController) and handling the different routes in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you’re looking for are nested resource controllers. These allow you to build routes like **/car/1/part/1**. This route would map to the action `CarPartController@show` and pass two parameters: the car ID and the part ID.

In terms of performance of cars/parts, I would say this is kinda like the “show” method (in that performance is not an entity in itself) so would create another method in your controllers like this:

```
class CarPartController extends Controller {

    public function show($carId, $partId)
    {
        // Show specified part for specified car
    }

    public function performance($carId, $partId)
    {
        // Show the performance for specified part on specified car
    }

}
```

Then your routes would look like this:

```
Route::get('car/{car}/performance', 'CarController@performance');
Route::get('car/{car}/part/{part}/performance', 'CarPartController@performance');

Route::resource('car', 'CarController');
Route::resource('car/{car}/part', 'CarPartController');
```

According to the Laravel documentation, non-resource methods have to be defined before the resource controllers.

You could also take this approach one step further and implement route–model binding, so that instances of your `Car` and `Part` model are injected into your controller actions rather than IDs:

```
Route::model('car', 'Car');
Route::model('part', 'Part');
```

And an example controller action:

```
public function performance(Car $car, Part $part)
{
    // Show performance for specified part on specified car
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that's great, excactly what I needed. When you're first starting out using routes, mvc and REST api there are a lot of concepts to get your head around so applying them can be confusing sometimes!

Comment: I guess my followup question is how or whether this fits in with REST principles because once I start using 
Route::get('car/{car}/performance', 'CarController@performance');
am I not then moving away from the strictly GET/PUT/DELETE etc. REST principles

Comment: The way I understood your app, the `performance` endpoints just collated statistics and returned them, as opposed to being an entity in themselves that could be updated, deleted etc. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. I think I just keep trying to think of performance as an entity which could be controlled using CRUD when all it is just more functionality added to the Car and Parts controllers for getting collated data. (I suppose of you think of the data as being live from a car gathering it, it should never be tampered with)

Comment: Cheers Martin, that's really helped me out!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any other questions and I’ll do my best to answer them.

Comment: You don't need to add the segment that contains the wildcard, you can write it like this:

`Route::resource('car.part', 'CarPartController');`

Comment: @cdarken What’s your comment in relation to? There isn’t a segment that contains a wildcard?

Comment: I was referring to this: `Route::resource('car/{car}/part', 'CarPartController');`. You can omit the {car} part and just write it as `car.part`

Comment: @cdarken That’s not a wildcard. That’s a route parameter.

Comment: @MartinBean you are right. And that parameter will be generated automatically if you use the dot.

Comment: Just a make sure follow up question. Should you create a different `PartController` for all the CRUD actions and use only the `CarPartController` as a show endpoint ? I'm gonna follow the same approach with `Posts` and `Comments` and i'm thinking what would be more appropriate. Do the `comment` CRUD actions in the `PostCommentController` or have a separate one like `CommentController` ?

Comment: @TerisL It really depends on a case-by-case basis as there’s no hard and fast rule. For comments, I’d probably give it its own controller (even though a comment would belong to a post). For CRUD-ing of car parts, I’d go with what would make the most sense to the user. Will a user navigate to a part by going through a car first? If so, I’d create a nested resource controller in that instance.